# stored procedure parameters in php

Tags: php, sql-server

Hi I am attempting to execute a stored procedure in my sqlserver database through php. I have the following code that has worked before when executing stored procedures. This time however the stored procedure includes parameters which I am having difficult time declaring. The two paramaters are TODATE and FROMDT, which are coming from date input boxes on a previous page.

```
enter  <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);

$serverName = "";
$userName = "";
$userPassword = '';
$dbName = "ENERGY";

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$dbName, "UID"=>$userName, "PWD"=>$userPassword, "MultipleActiveResultSets"=>true);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}



$FROMDT = 'POST_["FROMDT"]';
$TODATE = 'POST_["TODATE"]';
$params = array($FROMDT, $TODATE);


$sql = "ENERGY.dbo.P_KPI_DAILY_D $FROMDT $TODATE" ;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you execute the SP. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-execute.php

Comment: and these `POST_` are all incorrect. RTM on superglobals http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Hi Jay no I did not use sqlsrv_execute. I have done this way previously and it worked and I am unfamiliar with how to use the execute function so I was trying to stay away from that.

Comment: `'POST_["FROMDT"]'` <-- did you see the syntax's error's here? or not?

Comment: `stay away from that` what are you doing then with the SQL query?

Comment: No I did not receive any syntax errors. And thank you Fred you are 100% right I was rushing and never even noticed that.

Comment: $sql= executes the stored procedure that I have on my sql server database. That has worked before without having to use the execute function

Comment: `$sql=` cannot possibly execute a query on its own

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting the post data correctly.

Change

```
$FROMDT = 'POST_["FROMDT"]';
```

To:

```
$FROMDT = '';
if(isset($_POST['FROMDT'])){
    $FROMDT = $_POST['FROMDT'];
}
if($FROMDT == ''){
    // error handling
}
```

Also ensure you have the correct permissions write/execute the proc for the MSSQL user.

You could clean up your code a bit too. the below is extracted from a 'DataHandler' I built to automate binding parameters and allow for analytics.

```
<?php 

    define( "CONN_STRING", "sqlsrv:server=".DB_SERVER."; Database =".DB_NAME);

    try{
        $this->conn = new PDO($sConnString, $sDB_USER, $sDB_PASSWORD);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection failed: <bR>'; //.$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }


    $st = $conn->prepare( $sSQL );

    $this->st->bindValue( $sParamName, $_POST['ParmName'], PDO::PARAM_INT );

    $this->st->execute();



?>
```